# Can't able to fetch span class text

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, twitterapi-python

Please find the attached image . I want to fetch the highlighted part in the image,
i want to fetch this attributes  **1 · Trending ,#tuesdaymotivations,7,750 Tweets** .

please advise.
URL to fetch=https://twitter.com/explore/tabs/trending

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://twitter.com/explore/tabs/trending'

# scrolling and scraping tweets

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

trends = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="trends"]')
trend = trends[0]
trend.find_element_by_xpath('.//span').text
```

output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/PycharmProject/Twitter_trending/ss.py", line 13, in <module>
    trends = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="trends"]')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@data-testid="trends"]"}
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.72)
```

expected output:

```
1
·
Trending
#tuesdaymotivations
7,750 Tweets

2
·
Politics · Trending
#ModiResignOrRepeal
37.6K Tweets
3
·
Trending
#ThankfulTuesday
12.8K Tweets...etc
```

Comment: Is not `driver.find_elements` instead of `driver.find_element`?

Comment: i have tried both driver.find_elements & driver.find_element but no luck !

Comment: trends = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@data-testid="trend"]') small typo trends-> trend

Comment: still getting the [ ] empty list !

Answer (score 0):

Try to fetch the text using JavaScript. Use this code.

```
span = trend.find_element_by_xpath('.//span')
text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerText", span)
```

This method can also provide text from nested elements. Still not working then try css selector instead of xpath.

```
trends = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[data-testid="trends"]')
trend = trends[0]
span = trend.find_element_by_xpath('.//span')
text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerText", span)
```

Comment: tried both ways getting this error after using css selector AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_xpath' . is it driver related issue ?

Comment: Then use css selector again with the list opject too. or use it like this:
trends = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[data-testid="trends"] span')

And ignore the span variable and use trend as 2nd parameter in execute script.

Comment: it is printing "None" on the console after this. trends = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[data-testid="trends"] span')
text = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].innerText", trends)

Comment: Then check again i think you are not targeting the right element with text. I checked the url. It is not working for me.